Extract Main Domain from URLs in PostgreSQL Without Subdomains, Ports, or Query Parameters
I’m working with a PostgreSQL query where I need to extract the main domain (including the second-level domain and top-level domain) from URLs. However, the current approach using REGEXP_MATCH or SUBSTRING doesn’t handle all cases correctly. For example, it fails to parse URLs like {www.paylink.fr:443} (which should be paylink.fr) and {api.ornage.com} (which should be ornage.com)
   SELECT
       "Payments"."Id",
       REGEXP_MATCH("ClientRedirectUrl", '^https?://(?:[^/]+\\.)?([^/]+)') AS "PaymentDomain",
       REGEXP_MATCH("ClientUri", '^https?://(?:[^/]+\\.)?([^/]+)') AS "ClientDomain",
       REGEXP_MATCH("Site", '^https?://(?:[^/]+\\.)?([^/]+)') AS "UserDomain"
   FROM
       "public"."Payments"
       LEFT JOIN "public"."AppUsers" ON "Payments"."UserId" = "AppUsers"."Id"
       LEFT JOIN "public"."Clients" ON "Payments"."ClientId" = "Clients"."ClientId"
   WHERE
       "PayDate" >= (NOW() + INTERVAL '-3 day')


   SELECT
       "Payments"."Id",
       SUBSTRING("ClientRedirectUrl" FROM '^https?://(?:[^/]+\\.)?([^/]+)') AS "PaymentDomain",
       SUBSTRING("ClientUri" FROM '^https?://(?:[^/]+\\.)?([^/]+)') AS "ClientDomain",
       SUBSTRING("Site" FROM '^https?://(?:[^/]+\\.)?([^/]+)') AS "UserDomain"
   FROM
       "public"."Payments"
       LEFT JOIN "public"."AppUsers" ON "Payments"."UserId" = "AppUsers"."Id"
       LEFT JOIN "public"."Clients" ON "Payments"."ClientId" = "Clients"."ClientId"
   WHERE
       "PayDate" >= (NOW() + INTERVAL '-3 day')

How can I modify this query to correctly extract the main domains without any subdomains, ports, or query parameters?
Here is a sample of unparsed value:
ClientRedirectUrl: https://sonyco.it/wc-api/WC_paylink/?wc_order=673927
ClientUri: https://www.sonyco.it
Site: https://yzx80.paylink.net/

In other words, how to extract domain names and TLDs (here sonyco.it) from a list of URLs:
https://sonyco.it/wc-api/WC_paylink/?wc_order=673927
https://www.sonyco.it
https://yzx80.sonyco.it/ 
http://app.sonyco.it
www.sonyco.it:443
api.sonyco.it
http://www.sonyco.it:443


Perhaps like this https?://(?:api\.)?((?:[^\s.]+\.)+[a-z]{2,}) https://regex101.com/r/XWS5I4/1 Or without the www. like https://regex101.com/r/1Lde7N/1

merci, but it cannot extract any subdomains without need to hard code it: https://yzx80.paylink.net/

I am not sure what you mean by that, do you want to hard code it or do you not want to hard code it? See https://regex101.com/r/iR9vm8/1

I'm looking to avoid hardcoding specific subdomains @Thefourthbird

You could try to do it without regex. String functions and Case expression could be quite efficient...
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    urls ( ID, URL ) AS
      ( Select 1, 'https://sonyco.it/wc-api/WC_paylink/?wc_order=673927' Union All
        Select 2, 'https://www.sonyco.it' Union All
        Select 3, 'https://yzx80.sonyco.it/' Union All
        Select 4, 'http://app.sonyco.it' Union All
        Select 5, 'www.sonyco.it:443' Union All
        Select 6, 'api.sonyco.it' Union All
        Select 7, 'http://www.sonyco.it:443' Union All
        Select 8, 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78745653/extract-main-domain-from-urls-in-postgresql-without-subdomains-ports-or-query' Union All
        Select 9, 'https://www.info-retraite.fr/portail-services/login' 
      ), 

... create a cte that will format urls the same way ...
  urls_2 AS    -- url unification 
       ( Select ID, URL,
             SUBSTR( REPLACE( Case When Position( '/' in 
                                                   SubStr( Case When Position('//' in URL) = 0 
                                                                Then SubStr('//' || URL, Position('//' in URL) )
                                                           Else SubStr(URL, Position('//' in URL) )
                                                           End, 3 ) 
                                                 ) = 0
                                    Then SubStr( Case When Position('//' in URL) = 0 
                                                      Then SubStr('//' || URL, Position('//' in URL) )
                                                 Else SubStr(URL, Position('//' in URL) )
                                                 End, 3 ) || '/'
                              Else  SubStr( Case When Position('//' in URL) = 0 
                                                 Then SubStr('//' || URL, Position('//' in URL) )
                                            Else SubStr(URL, Position('//' in URL) )
                                            End, 3 )
                              End, ':', '/' 
                            ), 
                  1, 
                    POSITION( '/' IN REPLACE( Case When Position( '/' in 
                                                                   SubStr( Case When Position('//' in URL) = 0 
                                                                                Then SubStr('//' || URL, Position('//' in URL) )
                                                                           Else SubStr(URL, Position('//' in URL) )
                                                                           End, 3 ) 
                                                                 ) = 0
                                                    Then SubStr( Case When Position('//' in URL) = 0 
                                                                      Then SubStr('//' || URL, Position('//' in URL) )
                                                                 Else SubStr(URL, Position('//' in URL) )
                                                                 End, 3 ) || '/'
                                              Else  SubStr( Case When Position('//' in URL) = 0 
                                                                 Then SubStr('//' || URL, Position('//' in URL) )
                                                            Else SubStr(URL, Position('//' in URL) )
                                                            End, 3 )
                                              End, ':', '/' 
                                            ) 
                            ) - 1
                  )  as URL_2
          From   urls
        )

/*  -- R e s u l t :   (urls_2)
id  url_2
--  --------------------
 1  sonyco.it
 2  www.sonyco.it
 3  yzx80.sonyco.it
 4  app.sonyco.it
 5  www.sonyco.it
 6  api.sonyco.it
 7  www.sonyco.it
 8  stackoverflow.com
 9  www.info-retraite.fr    */

... extract domaines
--    M a i n    S Q L :
Select  ID, URL,  
        Case When Length(URL_2) - Length(Replace(URL_2, '.', '')) = 1 
             Then URL_2 
             When Length(URL_2) - Length(Replace(URL_2, '.', '')) = 2 
             Then SubStr(URL_2, Position('.' in URL_2) + 1 )
       End as DOMAIN_NAME
From    urls_2

/*            R e s u l t :
id  url                                                                                                                          domain_name
--  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  -----------------------------------
 1  https://sonyco.it/wc-api/WC_paylink/?wc_order=673927                                                                         sonyco.it
 2  https://www.sonyco.it                                                                                                        sonyco.it
 3  https://yzx80.sonyco.it/                                                                                                     sonyco.it
 4  http://app.sonyco.it                                                                                                         sonyco.it
 5  www.sonyco.it:443                                                                                                            sonyco.it
 6  api.sonyco.it                                                                                                                sonyco.it
 7  http://www.sonyco.it:443                                                                                                     sonyco.it
 8  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78745653/extract-main-domain-from-urls-in-postgresql-without-subdomains-ports-or-query   stackoverflow.com
 9  https://www.info-retraite.fr/portail-services/login                                                                          info-retraite.fr                      */

See the fidddle here.

Thank you for answer. Could you explain what this logic do: Length(URL_2) - Length(Replace(URL_2, '.', '')) = 2 

@sci9 That is a small trick that counts the number of dots in the string. If there are 2 then take the string after 1st dot, if there is one take the string as it is.

Lovely elegant answer - +1!
